# Extra hover CSS on Fabric control in SPFx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, css, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric

For all of my fabric control, I am getting extra hover CSS in my SPFx web part.

How can I remove that extra hover?

```
button:hover, input[type=button]:hover, input[type=reset]:hover, input[type=submit]:hover {
    /* border-color: #bdbdbd; */
    /* background-color: white; */
}
```

Attaching image what i get in my developer tool

[image]

Comment: Can you please try inspecting the HTML elements & see which class is applied on it which is causing hover effect? Then you can override the CSS on that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Office UI Fabric/Fluent UI [button control](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/button), it must have the `ms-Button` class applied to it.

So, you can override the CSS of that class in your code like below. You can change the color codes as per your requirements.

```
.ms-Button:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
    border-color: #0460a9 !important;
    background-color: #0460a9 !important;
}
```

If you want to override the CSS for:

- **Primary** buttons --> override the `.ms-Button--primary` class
- **Standard** buttons --> override the `.ms-Button--default` class

Comment: is there any way to remove the hover i have many buttons with different backgrounds

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754497/css-disable-hover-effect) & [this](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-remove-the-css-hover-behavior-from-an-element.html) if it helps!

Comment: Thank you  i made changes in as per you css !